# php dir() function does not read some entries

Tags: php

I am using the php dir() function on a directory like this:

```
/videos/1137
/videos/1137/0
/videos/1137/1
/videos/1137/2
/videos/1137/3
/videos/1137/4
```

The code runs in recursion but it does not pick some directories

The result is like

```
READING /videos/1137
READING /videos/1137/2
READING /videos/1137/3
```

although all the folders are having same permissions and even the user/group is same.

Is there some deficiency in the php dir() function that could be causing this?

Comment: Show us the php code.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you're doing in your code, since you haven't shown us any!

But here's a bit of code that will list all directories of a given folder, hopefully you can take it as inspiration for your own code.

```
<?php
function scan_videos(&$array, $path)
{
    $files = glob($path.'/*');
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if (is_dir($file))
        {
            $array[] = $file;
            scan_videos($array, $file);
        }
    }
}

$directories = array();
scan_videos($directories, 'videos');
print_r($directories);
?>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => videos/1137
    [1] => videos/1137/0
    [2] => videos/1137/1
    [3] => videos/1137/2
    [4] => videos/1137/3
    [5] => videos/1137/4
)
```